# Custom Automated Installation of Ubuntu Server wont boot

Tags: boot, server, uefi, preseed, kickstart

Got a question, hoping someone can give me an answer, which is probably obvious but I am lacking the knowledge as a junior system admin.

So I had to do various automated installs of Ubuntu Server for my job, I download the server image, unpack it, make the adequate changes via a combination of kickstart and preseed scripts, all that went fine, same as for packing back the iso file via mkisofs and I install it to a USB via Unetbootin (nothing else works) and I can only boot it on stations which have UEFI. It will not boot via normal boot, it just skips the device when selected from bios, no error or anything :/
I have tried booting the normal server image, which is installed via Ubuntu Startup Disk Image Creator, that boots normally, but when I try the same from my image, it doesn't work. Also, booting via a VM works, it correctly boots the non-UEFI install method and it continues to install as if it was a normal Ubuntu Server Image.
Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause? Just hit me with anything if you have the time.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a "normal" CD iso instead of a hybrid iso. Converting to a hybrid iso via

```
isohybrid image.iso
```

fixed everything.

[More info](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid)